# How to pass a file object to template in Django

Tags: django, file, django-templates, django-views

I am reading a file in **myView** & passing it to **myTemplate**

**myView**

```
fp = open('D:/python1/format.pdf', 'rb')        
data = fp.read()             

response = HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/pdf")
template = get_template('myTemplate.html')

variables = RequestContext(request, {'file':response})
output = template.render(variables)                
return HttpResponse(output)
```

**myTemplate**

```
<object id="pdf" height="100%" width="100%" type="application/pdf" data="{{file}}">
```

Check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/?from=olddocs#using-the-template-system).They have done a similar thing with csv file

**Note**:
I have done this successfully for an image file in zope (using python handler to read file and  Dtml to put the raw image data in 'src'). Check this [link](http://old.zope.org/Members/murphy/MySQL-BLOBs).

and I know that `Django shouldn't serve static files`.This is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data of the file as a string to the template as

```
fp = open('D:/python1/format.pdf', 'rb')        
data = fp.read()
variables = RequestContext(request, {'file': data})
output = template.render(variables)                
return HttpResponse(output)
```

Or you can serve it with web-server.

I don't think you can do something else. :-)

Comment: But will the browser take that string('file' in our case) as a pdf file ?

Comment: @Jibin Of course not. If you want so, why do you need template here? Just return `response` from the third line of your code.

Comment: Actually I wanted to create an inline pdf.So on one hand I had to send the normal rendered template as response while on the other hand  I had to send the pdf data with mime type set ,both at once.Never mind, I created a view to send the pdf & referenced a link to it in the rendered template.